# How to inject datarepository instance in Content provider using insert-koin

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-contentprovider, koin

Facing Issues  insert ContentProvider in  AppModule.

My app level Module is

```
module {
        single { TinyDB.getInstance(get()) }
        single { DataRepository(get()) }
        viewModel { HomeViewModel(get()) }
    }
```

I have no idea how to use ContentProvider in Module

I have tried Code

```
val dataRepo = inject(DataRepository::class.java)
```

this in  my Content provider but after this  my app start crashes 
and logcat show Error Massage

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider wastickerapps.newemojistickers.stickersforwhatsapp.whatsappUsages.StickerContentProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandAloneContext Koin instance is null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5562)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1509)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandAloneContext Koin instance is null
        at org.koin.standalone.StandAloneContext.getKoin(StandAloneContext.kt:68)
        at org.koin.standalone.KoinComponentKt.getKoinContext(KoinComponent.kt:42)
        at org.koin.standalone.KoinComponentKt.access$getKoinContext(KoinComponent.kt:1)
        at org.koin.standalone.KoinComponent$DefaultImpls.getKoin(KoinComponent.kt:36)
        at wastickerapps.newemojistickers.stickersforwhatsapp.whatsappUsages.StickerContentProvider.getKoin(StickerContentProvider.kt:27)
        at wastickerapps.newemojistickers.stickersforwhatsapp.whatsappUsages.StickerContentProvider.<init>(StickerContentProvider.kt:481)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1650)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5547)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5094) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1509) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate this part "I have no idea how to use ContentProvider in Module" ? It would also help if you can update the question with the DataRepository source code and the class where you inject DataRepository.

Comment: have you called `startKoin` method in your application class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Content Provider Initialise  Before  onCreate() method  in Application() class,I have called startKoin from attachBaseContext() method in Application() class implement KoinComponent in my ContentProvider class
and inject data repository in ContentProvider using this

```
 var dataRepo = inject<DataRepository>()
```

Here is the code for inject

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> inject(name: String = "", scope: Scope? = 
null, noinline parameters: ParameterDefinition = 
emptyParameterDefinition()) = lazy { get<T>(name, scope, parameters) }

inline fun <reified T : Any> get(name: String = "", scope: Scope? = 
null, noinline parameters: ParameterDefinition = e . 
mptyParameterDefinition()): T = getKoin().get(name, scope, parameters)
//
fun getKoin(): KoinContext = 
(org.koin.standalone.StandAloneContext.koinContext as KoinContext)
```